# What kind of stud or spacer is this? How should I remove it?

Tags: stud

Have you ever seen something like this? It seems to be a stud and a spacer merged together. This is where timing belt cover is fitted and tightened with a nut. Should I just use a spanner to open the hexagonal spacer and then remove the stud? I don't want to damage it.
There is a similar stud like this between camshaft pulleys. I want to remove that one because it doesn't let me install my cam pulley holder tool between cam gears. If I know how to remove this one, I can do the same for the one between pulleys.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it needs to be removed?

Comment: @jwh20 - I don't want to remove this one. There is another similar stud between camshaft pulleys which should be removed so that I can install a cam pulley holder between cam gears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s a long nut with a thread on both ends if you need a simple description.

If you need to make one quickly, having lost one for example, then a threaded rod cut to length and a handful of nuts works.

To remove just use the correct spanner - the ring end is better but depends on access and it can get close to the bottom to undo, it’s a one piece thing.

Comment: One piece thing? Is the spacer welded to the stud or attached to it somehow?

Comment: @NarimanAsgharian it is a one piece item as stated in my answer. Machined from a blank. In fact a piece apprentice mechanics get to make as part of training - well good training anyway.

Comment: The only thing I'd suggest differently for getting it off is to use a deep well socket if you've got one. 6-point better than a 12 (in this situation). Better access than a spanner, and in most cases you can put more torque on it without slipping.